# Can't post actions to a Facebook event

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I have my server side code create an event on Facebook, using a Facebook application user I created.

Then, I want mobile users of my app, that logs in to my app using FB connect, to be able to publish actions on that even's wall.
I tried doing it using code,curl or graph explorer, but nothing seems to work.
I suspect the only option is to publish actions using the user that created the event.

When I Post to a link like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/EVENT_ID/APP_NAMESPACE:ACTION
```

With the object as a parameter as well, I get the following error:

```
Requires a valid user is specified (either via the session or via the API parameter for specify
```

When I post to link like this :
https://graph.facebook.com/EVENT_ID/feed/APP_NAMESPACE:ACTION

I get an error:

```
Unknown path components: /APP_NAMESPACE:ACTION
```

Any way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that an event's `/feed` connection has no connection of `/APP_NAMESPACE:ACTION` type. This error message is correct.

Posting actions to or as a Page, Event, Group is not possible, nor is it possible to post actions to a friend's Timeline - only users can post actions, and only to their own timelines.

See the [Open Graph Mechanics](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/keyconcepts/#mechanics) part of the docs, it shows that **users** perform an **action** on an **object**. What you're trying to do is having a user take an action, and then post that to an event wall - that's not supported

Comment: If you found a doc on Facebook's site saying it was possible please comment with a link to the doc and i'll get it updated

Comment: You're probably right, couldn't see anything else the docs mention. thx